# How to enforce Fast API to use Path, Body and Query Parameters

Tags: python, fastapi

In FastAPI it automatically manages the parameters. But how to enforce that specific variable to only be taken from Path or Query or Body only.

Suppose this is the code.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


app = FastAPI()


@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
async def create_item(item_id: int):
    pass
```

Now i am calling this api as follows
`/items/1?item_id=2`
with payload Body

```
{
  'item_id' : 3
}
```

Here as developer I want to enforce the item_id in my function only be taken from say path. How can I force fastAPI to do that?

Comment: Something like `async def create_item(item_id: Annotated[int, Path(...)]):`? The same is also possible with `Query` and `Body` objects: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params-numeric-validations/

Comment: I'm wondering, why would you do this?  Good engineering is to make your API as flexible as possible.  If you can handle both, why not do it?